# Next JS express jwt authentication

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, next.js

I've implemented a `/api/login` to login a user. I also have a page `login.js`, that sends the form data to the login API. My login api checks the user credentials in my database and then signs a token and saves it to a cookie. 
My `/api/login`:

```js
await authCollection.findOne(
  {
    authCode: req.body.authcode,
  },
  function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!doc) return res.status(400).send('auth not found');
    if (doc) {
      const token = jwt.sign({ _id: doc._id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
      res
        .status(200)
        .cookie('token', token, {
          maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
          httpOnly: false,
        })
        .send(token);
    }
  },
);
```

I can protect my api routes with passing in a middleware like this:

```js
function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.cookies.token || '';
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).send('Access denied');
  }

  try {
    const decrypt = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    req.user = {
      id: decrypt.id,
      firstname: decrypt._id,
    };
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send('Invalid token');
  }
}
```

I do not understand how I can protect normal pages, which are in my `/pages` directory. Could somebody give me a hint in the right direction? I have already googled and read each page, but couldn't implement

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but it is better to use [`express-jwt`](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what I've done is to write an hoc `privateArea` which returns new component that fetches users `accessToken` from the API, then decodes it, if user is logged in, renders the wrapped page, otherwise, renders "restricted area" message.

```js
export function privateArea(PageComponent) {
  const PrivateArea = ({ accessToken, pageProps }) => {
    const user = decodeToken(accessToken);
    if (user) {
      return <PageComponent {...pageProps} />;
    } else {
      return <RestrictedArea />;
    }
  };

  PrivateArea.getInitialProps = async (...args) => {
    const accessToken = await api.getAccessToken();

    if (typeof PageComponent.getInitilProps === 'function') {
      const pageProps = await PageComponent.getInitilProps(...args);
    }
    return {
      accessToken,
      pageProps: pageProps || {},
    };
  };
  return PrivateArea;
}
```